# Display footer only if all the entries are shown

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have been working with jQuery DataTables for a few days and I need to display the footer only if all entries are shown.

For example, if I have `18` data rows in my table and is selected to display `9`, the footer should not be visible; and if all `18` are shown, the footer should become visible.

For now, the code for the Datatable footer looks something like this:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
       <th colspan="1" style="text-align:left">Round: </th>
       <th style="text-align:center"></th>
       <th style="text-align:center"></th>
     </tr>
```

And the JS code for it:

```
$("#TableDt" + rid).DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[18, 9], [18, 9]],
    bFilter: false,
    "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api(), data;
        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function (i) {
            var alb3;
            if (typeof i == 'string') {
                var alb = i.split(">");
                var alb2 = alb[1].split("<");
                alb3 = parseInt(alb2[0]);
            }
            else if (typeof i === 'number')
                alb3 = i;
            else
                alb3 = 0;
            return alb3;
        };
        // Total over all pages
        totalT = api
            .column(2)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            });
        totalP = api
            .column(1)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            });
        var TimeP = 0;
        var TimeT = 0;

        var time = totalP;
        var time2 = totalT;
        var h1 = Math.floor(time / 60);
        var m1 = time % 60;
        var h2 = Math.floor(time2 / 60);
        var m2 = time2 % 60;
        if (h1 <= 9) {
            if (m1 <= 9)
                TimeP = '0' + h1 + ':0' + m1;
            else
                TimeP = '0' + h1 + ':' + m1;
        }
        else if (m1 <= 9)
            TimeP = h1 + ':0' + m1;
        else
            TimeP = h1 + ':' + m1;
        if (h2 <= 9) {
            if (m2 <= 9)
                TimeT = '0' + h2 + ':0' + m2;
            else
                TimeT = '0' + h2 + ':' + m2;
        }
        else if (m2 <= 9)
            TimeT = h2 + ':0' + m2;
        else
            TimeT = h2 + ':' + m2;

        $(api.column(1).footer()).html(
            '' + TimeP + ''
        );
        $(api.column(2).footer()).html(
            '' + TimeT + ''
        );
    }
});
```

I didn't find anything that could help me with it. It is possible to display it only if all rows are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can attach a handler to [`search`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/search) event **before** your `DataTable()` initialization code. This event is fired when the table is filtered.

Then you can retrieve search query with [`search()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29) and determine whether to show or hide your footer based on the query.

```
$('#example').on( 'search.dt', function (e, settings) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
    var query = api.search();
    if(query === ''){
       $('#example tfoot').show();
    } else {
       $('#example tfoot').hide();    
    }       
});    

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/445ogLzL/) for code and demonstration.